Failed to resolve: testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+
Could not find any matches for testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+ as no versions of testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk are available.
syncing gradle file then this error suddenly shows up. no changes made from the app.....
